# Test Kitchen from Jenkins for AmazonLinux 2023

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, test-kitchen

I'm having an issue running "kitchen test" from Jennkins. When I run "kitchen test" from my local workstation, I'm using AWS EC2 instances to run tests against and I can get through all tests successfully.

Now, when I try to run this through a Jenkins pipeline, the AmazonLinux-2023 tests fail:

```
08:25:55  [34m$$$$$$ [SSH] connection failed, terminating (#<Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user ec2-user@10.103.16.108>)[0m
08:25:55  [34m       Removing automatic key pair kitchen-defaultamazonlinux2023-nologin-10edd750163b-2023-10-11T15:15:05Z-w1r41wsp[0m
08:25:55  >>>>>> ------Exception-------
08:25:55  >>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
08:25:55  >>>>>> Message: 1 actions failed.
08:25:55  >>>>>>     Failed to complete #create action: [SSH session could not be established] on default-amazonlinux2023
08:25:55  >>>>>> ----------------------
```

All my other platforms work just fine except the AmazonLinux2023 one. It works locally, but when I run it through Jenkins, I get the above error only in that one platform. I'm not sure what's different about this that would cause this specific issue.

Anyone got any ideas on this?

Thanks!